# closing browser after failing to login 3 times

Tags: php, javascript, authentication

after failing to login 3 times (wrong password, username), i want the browser/window/tab to be closed. how can i do this in javascript or php? and also can you give me some suggestions on what i can do to my system when user fails to login 3 times. thanks.

Answer (score 20):

Sorry, this is a bit outside the box, but: **Don't do it.** There are good reasons why stuff like `window.close()` won't do it without a prompt. I admit there are conceivable cases where this might be a good approach, but by circumventing user control measures like this you'll probably end up shooting yourself in the foot, even if the purpose is good.

Few options on how this foot-shooting might occur:

- You think that it's a good idea to do it in your case, but whoops, the users don't think so. Even though you were sure it would be the best usability thing anyone's ever thought of.
- The hackaround involves some stuff that breaks some other stuff somewhere. In another browser. In an older version. With a certain browser plugin. With some unusual user settings.
- Future browser version makes the hackaround fail miserably, and you've somehow built your interaction model to depend on the hackaround, even though you were sure you made an alternative approach just in case... only you didn't, in that one place, because you were using the hackaround yourself and didn't notice you expected it to always work.
- The hackaround works fine... but only when you're watching. In some pretty normal conditions that shouldn't affect it, it suddenly breaks something else, and you end up spending days on debugging some weird fringe issue that ends up being caused by the hackaround. I mean, the hackaround shouln't have caused something like that. It really shouldn't. But it did.

Comment: Agreed, anything that attempts to control the user's browser should be discouraged.

Well written answer.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Ilari Kajaste when he says "Don't do it". The last thing a user wants is undexpected behaviour. I've never come across a website that closes a window after invalid login attempts so it's almost certianly going to confuse your users. Secondly it's going to destroy any history that the user has in their back button which will frustrate some users.
When you get multiple failed logins you could prevent them from logging in for a specific period of time (say 10 mins). You could do this by storing the time of their 3rd invalid login to your database, and checking at subsequent logins how long it is since their last attempt. If this is under your threshold then you don't even check the password. Just make sure you explain that someone cannot login for 10 mins after 3 failed logins

Answer (score 4):

In JavaScript you can call...

```
window.close();
```

But this will cause a prompt to be displayed by the browser asking the user to confirm they want to close the browser (unless you are closing a child window that you previously spawned).

There is no way around these prompts.

Answer (score 3):

Just temporary block user's account in server side for n minutes.

Answer (score 1):

can you redirect page to another page?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to block a user account, don't do it after 3 attempts.
I've got so many passwords I have to try at least 5 times on some websites before I get the correct one....

Answer (score 1):

1. Secure against further login attempts on the server side.
2. Either redirect to an error page, as drorhan mentioned, or display a "sorry, too many login attempts, try again in an hour" type message on the login page instead of the login/password input boxes.

As SEO tells us, you really never want to force a user away from your site, in SEO that's called lost Return On Investment the opposite of what you do SEO to accomplish.  :p  Redirecting to another page in your own site is by far preferable.